# PLY recognizing token in lex but not in yacc

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, yacc, lex, ply

I'm using ply and defined my tokens as

```
reserved = {
    'main': "MAIN",
    'if': "IF",
    'elif': "ELIF",
    'else': "ELSE",
    'while': "WHILE",
    'input': "INPUT",
    'print': "PRINT",
    'int': "INT",
    'float': "FLOAT",
    'bool': "BOOL",
    'char': "CHAR",
    'void': "VOID",
    'return': "RETURN"
}

# All tokens must be named in advance.
tokens = [  'PLUS', 'MINUS', 'TIMES', 'DIVIDE', 'LPAREN', 'RPAREN',
            'EQUALS', 'NEQUALS', 'LT', 'GT', 'LTE', 'GTE', 'OR', 'AND', 'ASSIGN',
            'RCURLY', 'LCURLY', 'RSQUARE', 'LSQUARE', 'SEMICOLON', 'CONSTINT',
            'CONSTFLOAT', 'CONSTCHAR', 'CONSTSTRING', 'CONSTBOOL', 'ID', 'COMMA'   ] + list(reserved.values())


t_COMMA             = r'\,'
t_SEMICOLON         = r'\;'
t_LCURLY            = r'\{'
t_RCURLY            = r'\}'
t_LSQUARE           = r'\['
t_RSQUARE           = r'\]'
t_LPAREN            = r'\('
t_RPAREN            = r'\)'
t_EQUALS            = r'\=\='
t_ASSIGN            = r'\='
t_NEQUALS           = r'\!\='
t_GT                = r'\>'
t_GTE               = r'\>\='
t_LT                = r'\<'
t_LTE               = r'\<\='
t_PLUS              = r'\+'
t_MINUS             = r'\-'
t_TIMES             = r'\*'
t_DIVIDE            = r'\/'
t_AND               = r'\&\&'
t_OR                = r'\|\|'

# Ignored characters
t_ignore = ' \t'

# CONSTANT LITERALS
def t_CONSTBOOL(t):
    r'(true|false)'
    t.value = 1 if t == "true" else 0
    return t

def t_CONSTRING(t):
    r'\".*\"'
    t.value = t.value[1:-1]
    return t

def t_CONSTFLOAT(t):
    r'\d+\.\d+'
    t.value = float(t.value)
    return t

def t_CONSTINT(t):
    r'\d+'
    t.value = int(t.value)
    return t

# ID
def t_ID(t):
    r'[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_1-9]*'
    t.type = reserved.get(t.value, 'ID')
    return t

def t_CONSTCHAR(t):
    r'\'.\''
    t.value = t.value[1]
    return t

# Ignored token with an action associated with it
def t_ignore_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += t.value.count('\n')

# Error handler for illegal characters
def t_error(t):
    print(f'Illegal character {t.value[0]!r}')
    t.lexer.skip(1)
    
lexer = lex.lex()
```

When tokenizing the string `main factorial_iterativo() { int r = 1;}` I get the expected tokens

```
LexToken(MAIN,'main',1,0)
LexToken(ID,'factorial_iterativo',1,5)
LexToken(LPAREN,'(',1,24)
LexToken(RPAREN,')',1,25)
LexToken(LCURLY,'{',1,27)
LexToken(INT,'int',1,29)
LexToken(ID,'r',1,33)
LexToken(ASSIGN,'=',1,35)
LexToken(CONSTINT,1,1,37)
LexToken(SEMICOLON,';',1,38)
LexToken(RCURLY,'}',1,39)
```

However when parsing as follows (excluding unrelated definitions)

```
def p_assign(p):
    """
    assign : ID array_assign ASSIGN expression SEMICOLON
    """

def p_array_assign(p):
    """
    array_assign : dims
                 | empty
    """
def p_dims(p):
    """
    dims : LSQUARE expression RSQUARE
    """
def p_empty(p):
    '''
    empty : 
    '''
    pass

def p_error(p):
    if p is not None:
        print ("Line %s, illegal token %s" % (p.lineno, p.value))
    else:
        print ("Unexpected end of input")
    exit()
```

I get `Line 1, illegal token =`

I've tried moving the token regex definitions thinking maybe there was some prioritization happening between EQUALS AND ASSIGN to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Your evidence for the claim that Ply's parser component (`ply.yacc`) is not correctly recognising `=` as the `ASSIGN` token is a message which you yourself produce, in the `p_error` method. With all due respect, this is not a reliable diagnostic tool. The error message is, at best, misleading.

Ply's parser calls `p_error` when it is unable to find an appropriate action for the lookahead token. That could mean the token has not been correctly recognised, but we know that's not the case here; the lexical analyser identifies the token, and `ply.yacc` uses `ply.lex` to split the input into tokens. In other words, there is only one lexical anslyser, and as far as you have tested, it's working just fine.

Most of the time, when `p_error` is called, the input contains a syntax error. Or, at least, the input does not conform to the grammar. So the next step is to trace through the parser and ensure that the language it recognises is exactly the language you want to recognize.

But that's not possible without seeing the entire grammar, or at least a much larger extract. So I'll leave it at that.